# How can I determine whether my processor is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, 32-bit, computer-architecture

How can I determine whether my processor is 32-bit or 64-bit? My processor is AMD Phenom 8450 triple-core.

Comment: Use CPU-Z utility and it will also list it's available features.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): 
[How to tell if a Windows computer has a 64-bit CPU or OS](https://superuser.com/q/208312/358766)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could search google/newegg for your particular processor, if you know it by name, and read the specs. The specs on your processor says: 64-Bit Support: Yes.
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103254

But i'd vote for someone else's answer if they could give a quick and easy way to check this without having to know your processor's model. Maybe it says in the bios on boot up?

Comment: Good point, I would think the OS, or at the very least the BIOS would tell you.

Answer (score 12):

Another way would be to use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html). In addition to bitness (AMD64 or EM64T) of the processor, it will display other useful characteristics of the processor.

Another way would be to check directly on the website of the manufacturer. Intel has a database of its processors [here](http://ark.intel.com/) and it's quite nice. Unfortunately, AMD does not have such nice interface, but you can always go to their homepage and poke around. [Here](http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUResult.aspx) is the list of their desktop processors. VIA's processors seem to be listed [here](http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/processors/).

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you on?

In Linux / Mac OS X all you have to do is open a terminal and type `uname -p`

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted to know that. The question was about the actual processor capability, not what operating system was running on it.

Answer (score 2):

Open the System Information

Open the Start menu, and click on Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> System Information

Look in the System Summary

The System Information tool will display detailed information about your Windows operating system. Once opened it will show the "System Summary" – it’s an overview of your computer and operating system.

Look for the System Type Item

On the right hand side of the window you will see a list of items. Look for the item called "System Type".

The value of this item will tell you whether your computer is 32-bit or 64-bit:

```
x86-based PC: It’s a 32-bit computer.
x64-based PC: It’s a 64-bit computer.
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: A 32 bits Windows can run on an 62 bits CPU.

Comment: User wanted to know what type of processor they had - the above tells them.

Comment: @johnprobe if you install a 32bit version of windows, it will always say x86-based pc, even if the cpu has a 64-bit instruction set. as such, your answer is misleading rather than helpful

Answer (score 1):

Google for the processor's name. I found a [wikipedia article about AMD processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Phenom_microprocessors#.22Toliman.22_.28B2_.26_B3.2C_65_nm.2C_triple-core.29).

It states, that the 8450 supports AMD64, which means it is a [64Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#AMD64) processor.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge all Phenom series are AMD/64.  If you need assurance and you're using a Linux or BSD OS take a look at what dmesg says on bootup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this program created by Steve Gibson of Gibson Research Corporation called [SecurAble](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm). This tool will not only tell you if it is a 32/64 bit processor, it will also tell you if the CPU supports hardware DEP protection and if it supports Hardware Virtualization.

The program requires no installation at all. It simply uses a signed driver and communicates with the processor.

Comment: Unfortunately it's Windows only. I'd like a version that runs under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know external 3rd party software. You can just use the terminal prompt to check it.

If you are using Linux:

```
uname -m
```

return x8_64 if 64bit and i386 if 32bit

or you can use the easy command:

```
arch
```

Return if 64 or 32

If you are using Windows. Open command prompt and run the command:

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

return whether 32 or 64 bit.

If you are running OSX:

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
```

Return

```
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No   (this output for 32-bit kernel)
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: Yes (this is output for 64-bit kernel)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - only tells you the OS type, not CPU type (x64 can run x86 OS)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you can simply type either:

```
wmic cpu get datawidth
```

or:

```
echo %processor_architecture%
```

in command prompt. `wmic cpu get addresswidth` is for the OS, not the CPU, in case someone was wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Phenom x3 processors are basically quad-cores with one core locked (mostly due to defects). These are all 64-bit. 
PS - If you're interested, you should google to see and try to unlock your fourth core. A lot of AMD x3 have a working fourth core that can be unlocked to make your processor a quad core.

Answer (score 0):

Below command on 'command prompt' would display CPU name and family.

> wmic cpu get Description

on a 64bit OS

> Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1

on a 32bit OS

> x64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1

Name of Processor on a 64bit or 32bit OS

> wmic cpu get Name

Results in

> Name
>   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz