# How to tell if a Windows computer has a 64-bit CPU or OS

Tags: windows, cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit, community-faq-proposed

How you can check if your Windows computer

- Has an x86 (32-bit) or x86-64 (64-bit) processor?
- Is running a 32 bit or 64 bit operating system?

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: win xp professional

Comment: Use Linux and http://superuser.com/questions/208301/linux-command-to-return-number-of-bits-32-or-64 (and I'm sure there's a duplicate for Windows as well).

Comment: I don't have lInux

Comment: just run in command line 'wmic os get osarchitecture'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are on 64-bit XP, under `C:\` you will see a "Program Files" as well as "Program Files (x86)" folder.

System properties will also reflect a 64-bit OS:

[image]

Comment: I did that but I didn't see where it says 32bit. So maybe I gather that my XP Pro is 32 bit if 64 bit is not listed.

Comment: @tint, correct.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all processors produced since 2006 support the 64-bit instruction set, and can run either a 32-bit or a 64-bit operating system. Running a 64-bit OS *requires* an x86-64 CPU, but you do not *need* a 64-bit OS to use one of these CPUs.

## Hardware

Almost all AMD processors since the Athlon 64 have supported 64-bit instructions. If you have an AMD processor, it probably can run a 64-bit OS.

Almost all Intel processors since the Core 2 series have supported 64-bit. If you have a Core 2, or Core *i*<sub>x</sub> processor, it can run a 64-bit OS. The only exceptions are a few of the Atom netbook processors. To check whether your processor version supports x64, look it up in Intel's [processor database](http://ark.intel.com/).

## Software

Mac OS X has supported x64 since OS X 10.4 Tiger, and has been x64 only since 10.6 Snow Leopard.

There have been 64-bit versions of Windows since Windows 2000 Server, but did not enter mainstream until Windows Vista. Many computers sold with Windows today come with 64-bit Windows 7. You can check whether you have 64-bit Windows installed by going to My Computer and clicking on System Properties.

[image: windows 64 bit]

Comment: I would correct the first sentence to: "Almost all processors produced since *2010* support the 64-bit instruction set" There were still alot of 32-bit laptops released in 2007/2008.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Windows XP then you are most likely running a 32-Bit Operating System, since the 64-Bit WinXP Version is extremely rare (for a good reason since it's largely unsupported).

If the PC itself is 64-Bit compatible is trickier to find out in that case. Try downloading [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and check if Instructions lists something like EM64T, AMD64, x86-64 or similar. If in doubt, please post what CPU-Z displays for Name, Specification and Instructions.

Comment: ok, so there is no way to check in PC if its 32 bit

Comment: There is, but not by simple command line. Using autoit, the @CPUARC macro will return 32-bit or 64-bit for the processor and @OSARCH will tell you if the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit. This will work on any windows machine. I could probably write a little script for this in a few minutes.

Comment: @MaQleod: That's nice of you. Would appreciate it. Is there a way to check without installing it? As much as possible I don't want to install because, it makes my PC slow

Comment: the link to the compiled version doesn't require any installation.

Answer (score 4):

Using [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), run this script:

```
If @CPUARCH = "x86" Then
    $CPUARCH = "32-bit"
Else
    $CPUARCH = "64-bit"
EndIf

If @OSARCH = "x86" Then
    $OSARCH = "32-bit"
Else
    $OSARCH = "64-bit"
EndIf

MsgBox(64,"OS and CPU Architechure","The CPU is " & $CPUARCH & " and the OS is " & $OSARCH)
```

There is a [compiled version](http://www.mediafire.com/?96ksgkt7jjem5hw) here if you don't want to download autoit and compile it yourself. Note, this will work on 2K/XP/VISTA/7

Comment: hmm, how to I run this script? Do I need to run this in the command prompt? I'm sorry as I'm a beginner in a programming world

Comment: the link for the compile version looks strange to me, but I have to download it from here.

Comment: Sorry about the spelling error I just noticed, was trying to do it quickly with kids screaming at me, I'll fix it when I have time, but it really doesn't make much difference in how the app works.

Comment: thanks MaQleod, I'm interested how to try this script. How do you run a script? Not really sure.

Comment: If you got the compiled version, you just run it, like any exe, it'll pop up a message box with both the OS and Processor architecture. If you installed autoit first, you just paste the above script to a text file, save it as a .au3 file and right click and choose "run script".

Comment: @MaQleod:the link requires me to download: this is what I got if I clicked on the compiled version: http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/Test/architecture.png

Comment: @tintincute: thats the program. You don't need to install it, just unzip it and run it. The file itself has been compiled into an executable, you don't need anything else for it to run, the message box will tell you both what your OS and processor architecture is (32 or 64 bit)

Comment: @MaQleod: thanks for your reply. but the site looks strange to me. so I just click on the architectur.zip?

Comment: honestly, I don't normally use that site for putting up files, but my regular was down, it appears I didn't do it right, I'll try and correct it with my normal site

Answer (score 2):

Below is a list of methods for checking whether your currently installed Operating System is 32 or 64 bit, and whether your processor can support a 64 bit OS.

Note that the methods will vary depending on your version of Windows.

---

### Any Windows Version

#### Operating System

If you are using a 64 bit version of Windows, you will have **Program Files (x86)** and **Program Files** on your `C:\` drive.

If you are using a 32 bit version of Windows, only the **Program Files** folder will be present.

---

### Windows 10

#### Operating System & Processor

Right click the **Start Button** then click **System**.

[image: Windows 10 Right Click Start Menu]

The OS and Processor type will be shown under the **System** heading next to **System Type**.

[image: Windows 10 System Information]

*Source: [WD Support - How to determine if Windows OS is 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64)](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=9405)*

---

### Windows 8

#### Operating System & Processor

From the Desktop, press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> (*Windows Key + i*), then click **PC Info**.

[image: Windows 8 Settings Charm]

The OS and Processor type will be shown under the **System** heading next to **System Type**.

[image: Windows 8 System Information]

*Source: [Picohelp - How to Check if Windows 8 is 32-bit or 64-bit Version](http://www.picohelp.com/958/how-to-check-if-windows-8-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-version.html)*

---

### Windows 7/Vista/Server 2008

#### Operating System

Open the **Start Menu**, right click **Computer**, and select **Properties**. The OS type will be listed under **System**.

[image: Windows 7 System Information]

*Source: [WikiHow - Check if Your Computer is 64-Bit](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-if-Your-Computer-Is-64-Bit)*

#### Processor

*This method may require Administrator rights.*

1. Open Performance Information and Tools by clicking the **Start** button, and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the search box, type **Performance Information and Tools**, and
   then, in the list of results, click **Performance Information and Tools**.
2. Click **View and print detailed performance and system information**.
3. In the **System** section, you can see what type of operating system you're currently running under **System type**, and whether or not you can run a 64-bit version of Windows under **64-bit capable**. (If your computer is already running a 64-bit version of Windows, you won't see the **64-bit capable** listing.)

*Source: [Microsoft Support - 32-bit and 64-bit Windows: Frequently asked questions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15056/windows-7-32-64-bit-faq)*

---

### Windows XP

#### Operating System

Open the **Start Menu**, right click **My Computer**, and select **Properties**. The **General** tab will show if your system uses a 64 bit-OS under the **System** header.

[image: Windows XP System Properties]

*Screenshot courtesy of [John T](https://superuser.com/a/208320/358766)*

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers don't actually prove that your system is 64bit.  They simply tell you whether or not you have a 64bit OS installed.  I can suggest you do that too.  But, if your copy of windows isn't 64bit (because you can install 32 bit windows on 64bit systems) then I suggest you install CPU-Z.

Once you've install it, run CPU-Z and look for the EM64T under instructions on the CPU tab.

Comment: EM64T only applies to Intel chips. AMD chips will show as "x86_64". +1

Answer (score 1):

Command line, in Windows:

```
wmic computersystem
```

Just the system type:

```
wmic computersystem get systemtype
```

Terminal, in Linux:

```
sudo lscpu
```

Just the system type:

```
sudo lscpu | grep Architecture
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on My Computer and then click on Properties.

Comment: I did that but there is no way here that says it's 32 bit

Comment: Are you using XP? Vista? 7? ME?

Comment: I'm using XP Professional

Comment: So in the screenshot above, (http://i.imgur.com/wJa5R.gif) when it says x64 Edition thats because he has the 64-bit version of Windows XP installed. What does yours say when you open up the properties?

Comment: nothing. Mine is quite old I guess. It just say: Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3. So I assumed that this is only 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast option to run the command line:

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

my output is

> OSArchitecture
>
> 64-bit