# Is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67 GHz a 64 bit Processor?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit, intel-core-i5

How do i know if my pc can run **64x bit**? I have problems with 32x bit so i need 64x bit.

I have a:

> **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67 GHz**

I've tried to find some help on the internet, and on the Windows site, but they're just so unhelpfull so if you guys could help me, i would really appreciate it

Comment: Find your processor here and look at what instruction set it supports - http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-i5-processor.html

Comment: I think you may be missing what your question really should be - what are the issues you are seeing with 32bit?  Secondly, why do you think that a move to 64bit will change anything?

Comment: You can find this easily on any Windows 7 system by going to Start, Control Panel, then System.  On Windows 8, go to the Start menu, type Control Panel, click it when it appears in search, then go to System.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a computer has a 64-bit CPU or OS](http://superuser.com/questions/208312/how-to-tell-if-a-computer-has-a-64-bit-cpu-or-os)

Comment: @LawrenceC - and how can you tell if you don't have physical possession of the computer, but you do have the technical spec / description?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Intel i3, i5 and i7 cpus are all capable of running 64bit operating systems. Windows XP thru Win 8 all are available in 32 or 64bit versions.
A 32 bit OS can only run 32 bit apps, but a 64 bit OS can run both 32 and 64 bits apps. Most desktop processors became available with 64bit capability since the mid-1990's. Now, you can assume that any currently available desktop CPU has 64bit capability. Even smaller ARM processors, like those that run cellphones are becoming available. [More history of 64bit processing is here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#History)

Comment: IMO, this answers the question but misses the root, which is not to only tell them the answer (limited scope of usage) but to educate them on how to find the answer as well.  That not only helps the OP here, but a future visitor with a similar question.

Answer (score 5):

*While jdh answered the question, I think that it doesn't really help people in the future with other processors figure it out themselves.*

The best way to find information on you CPU is to simply use the manufacturer's site. For Intel: http://ark.intel.com/.  For AMD, they don't have as good a site AFAIK, so Newegg's feature list is adequate.

Once there, you really care about the "Instruction Set".  (jdh has great info there for you).

For your processor, you can indeed handle x64 (as can nearly all modern cpu's) ([source](http://ark.intel.com/products/42915/Intel-Core-i5-750-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz)):

[image]